# Licensing system for Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, licensing

Does anyone have experience in creating a licensing system for a Flex Application. My Flex application is a swf which is embedded in a aspx page. For data retrieval it accesses web services.

My intention is to sell it to my customers on license base. (Eg: Using a Serial Number).

Comment: Flex is just a frontend technology. Any kind of authentication must be handled on the server side.

Comment: So if I to create a Flex application and release it to the customer. what is the way to go. block the services from accessing

Answer (score 1):

I think I've answered this a lot; but I can't find it.  Here are two services:

1. [NitroLM](http://nitrolm.com)
2. [Sharify](http://www.sharify.it/)

There used to be another, I think, but I can't remember the name and my Google-Fu is failing me.

You didn't go into details on how you want your licensing scheme to work; so it's tough to give you specifics.  The algorithm is not complicated, but the details can become very much so.

I built something for Flextras in the early days that would watermark non licensed Flex components.  The gist is:

1. Load serial Number.
2. Perform some secret sauce algorithm!  In the Flextras model this
   was done at runtime based on a serial number specified at compile
   time.  It did some checking of the serial number data against the
   domain, the component, and the component's version.  For an
   application you may want to check other data (The Username for
   example) and possibly against some central repository server.
3. If the user is allowed access? If so then let them have at it.
4. If not; then show them the "invalid" message/screen/etc..